# PHP Mysql echo's from second row

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple MYSQL query that echo's the data in the table, but in stead of starting at the first one, it starts at the second one.
i have no idea why, ive tried several other codes but nothing helped.
here's my code: (don't mind the dutch language please) ;)

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Landlijst`");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

if (!$result) {
die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row["ID"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["Land"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Hoofdstad"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Werelddeel"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Inwoners"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

i also have the idea there might be something wrong with my table setup:
(i cant post images yet) :(
https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/ujDZeW7m5QG-1bwPWmKUmMVJiNT38Fv8epGcoQh8jDXr/Naamloos.png

Comment: Please notice that the MySQL-extension is deprecated and one should use MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're needlessly fetching the first row (and then discarding it) before entering your loop:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Landlijst`");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  // <--- here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  DO WHILE, and define your $row variable two times. Like this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row["ID"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["Land"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Hoofdstad"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Werelddeel"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Inwoners"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

You can use a FOR Loop to, this problem not happens.

Results aren't starting at row 2,  stats at row 1, but, in while, the first validation "says" to while "ok, i have results, keep looping.".  When we use  do-while,  we process the first result and print then at your table, and after we verify for another re